# Problema al subir una imagen con NodeJS, Typescript y Fastify (backend)

Tags: nodejs, typescript, oracle, blob

¡Hola!

Estoy haciendo un backend (usando NodeJS, TypeScript y Fastify, además de fastify-multipart) con un método post que recibe una request con varios parámetros recibidos de un form-data desde postman. El problema es que no veo el error con el formato de la imagen al intentar subirla a una BBDD Oracle. Os dejo el código divido por archivos a ver si podéis ayudarme a ver el problema:

post.routes.ts:

```
const uploadImage = (app: FastifyInstance): void => {
 app.register(fastifyMultipart, { attachFieldsToBody: true });
 app.post<{ Body: RequestInterface }>("/imageupload", controllers.uploadImage);
};
```

upload.controller.ts:

```
uploadImage: async (req: FastifyRequest<{ Body: RequestInterface }>, res: FastifyReply) 
=> {
    try {

      const { codpar, image } = req.body;

      const imageData = await image.toBuffer();

      return res
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .send(
          await uploadImage(
            String(codpar?.value),
            Buffer.from(imageData.toString(), 'base64')
          )
        );
    } catch (e: any) {
      logger.error(
        "uploadImage: " +
          JSON.stringify({ error: { name: e.name, description: e.message } })
      );
      throw Error(e.message);
    }
  },
```

upload.service.ts:

```
export const uploadImage = async (
  codpar?: string,
  image?: Buffer
) => {

    await uploadPartImage(codpar, image);

  return getResponse(messageResponse);
};
```

update.database.ts:

```
const uploadPartImage = async (
  codpar?: string,
  image?: Buffer
) => {

  const imageBlob = {
    dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
    type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_BLOB,
    val: image?.toString(),
  };

  const imageReturn = {
    type: orclParamType.STRING, //2001
    dir: orclParamDirection.BIND_OUT, //3003
  };

  const queryText =
    "BEGIN " +
    "INCTCP.Pkg_Ni_Partes.wsins_foto_anomalia_parte" +
    "(:p_codpar, :p_picdata, :p_return);" +
    "END;";
  return (
    await query(queryText, [codpar, imageBlob, imageReturn])
  ).rows;
};
```

Y todo esto me da el error:

```
uploadImage: {"error":{"name":"Error","description":"NJS-011: encountered bind value and type mismatch"}}
```

¿Podríais orientarme al respecto? He intentado en el type tanto BLOB como DB_TYPE_BLOB o BUFFER y nada.

Gracias